# Creating PPT with Perl - error 0x8001010a "application is busy"

Tags: perl, powerpoint, win32ole

actually I'm writing a Perl script for creating a powerpoint presentation automatically. The reason for this is, that I need really much Slides with the same look.

So I always copy the first slide and just update the text in the boxes with new text out of a excel file.

ATM it works fine but rly unstable, so sometimes the PP is created successfully and sometimes the creation is interrupted with the error

```
Win32::OLE<0.1712> error 08001010a: "The message filter indicated that the application is busy" in Method/Propertyget "TextFrame" at [Pfad] line 150
```

Would be nice if someone could help me to fix that or explain to me where this error comes from

Comment: Pearl or PERL?  If the latter, you might want to update the tags on your post.  What is your code doing when you run into the error?  It's ALWAYS best to post the relevant code with enough context to make it clear what's going on. Also, look for problems that might be introduced by the fact that PowerPoint only allows a single instance of itself (unlike Word/Excel) and that there are likely to be issues if you try to open/alter a second copy of a file that's already open.

Comment: oh yeah i mean perl, just misspelled it.

Comment: @Stevetro: You know you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39642524/edit) to fix that, right?

Comment: @DaveCross BT.DT. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: Pedantically, it's "Perl", not "PERL" :-)

Comment: @DaveCross Dang, you're right. I'd always read that it was an acronym for "Practical Extraction and Report Language" but this turns out to be a backronym.  And in looking this up, I found that Wall originally planned to call it Pearl, but found that there was already another language by that name.  IAC, "Perl" it shall become.  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @Stevetro There is a possible solution from the [perl monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=488318)